# Have any "New Age movements" worshiped solar eclipses?

Tags: eclipse

So I recently saw the August 21 solar eclipse.  I was told I was being "new age" by viewing it.  Is there any evidence of "new age" views worshiping it?  I have asked a similar [question here](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/are-there-any-stories-that-present-solar-eclipses-as-a-good-sign).  There is no site that I thought this question had a perfect fit, but this site seemed the closest.

Comment: This is going to be a rabbit-hole since there's no formal canon for "new agey" but I like questions on modern mythologies!

Comment: @DukeZhou Would this be classified as a mythology, or a cult? Are such questions on-topic?

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo considering the moderator(Semaphore) created a `new-age`tag just for this question I believe it is considered to be borderline.  If multiple people express this question is not acceptable I am happy to delete it.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo I'd say mythology definitely, because the beliefs are widespread and varied.  But they are also almost certainly used in cults.  But don't forget, there were many ancient mystery cults.